# Ext JS Format DATA to "DD-MM-YYYY"

Tags: javascript, web, extjs, extjs4

Using `ExtJS 4.2.3`, I have FORM with textfield. I need to get value from store to the field. Having problems with my attempt to format data in the desired format. Asking for help with syntax to format data to `DD-MM-YYYY`.

**Data in source:** `/Date(1417986000000)/`

After trying to get data by:

```
Form_window.query('textfield[name="DateField"]')[0].setValue(NewDATA_store.getAt(1).get('DateData'))
```

**What I get:** `Mon Dec 08 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (RTZ 2 (winter))`

**Result what I need:** `08.12.2014`

Comment: You have any special reason to use textfield instead of datefield? http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Date

Comment: If the field is only to display the date use the datefield with the following configs: readOnly: true, format: 'd-m-Y'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **ExtJS** **[`Date`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.Date)** singleton class available you need to use [`Ext.Date.formate()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.Date-method-format) method of this.

A **`Date`** class set of useful static methods to deal with date Note that if [Ext.Date](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/#!/api/Ext.Date) is required and loaded, it will copy all methods / properties to this object for convenience.

Example usage (note that you must escape format specifiers with '\' to render them as character literals):

```
//Current date
var dt = new Date();
console.log(Ext.Date.format(dt, 'Y-m-d')); // 2017-12-26
console.log(Ext.Date.format(dt, 'F j, Y, g:i a')); //December 26, 2017, 11:28 am
console.log(Ext.Date.format(dt, 'l, \\t\\he jS \\of F Y h:i:s A')); //Tuesday, the 26th of December 2017 11:28:02 AM
```

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2bb5)**, I have create a demo using `form`, 'textfield' and `store`. I hope this will help you or guide you.

```
 Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
     storeId: 'dateStore',
     fields: [{
         name: 'DateData',
         type: 'date'
     }],
     data: [{
         DateData: new Date()
     }]
 });

 Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
     title: 'Simple Form',
     bodyPadding: 5,
     width: 350,

     layout: 'anchor',
     defaults: {
         anchor: '100%'
     },

     // The fields
     defaultType: 'textfield',
     items: [{
         fieldLabel: 'Today Date',
         name: 'DateField',
         readOnly: true
     }],
     renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
     listeners: {
         afterrender: function (form) {
             var store = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('dateStore'),
                 date = store.getAt(0).get('DateData');

             form.down('[name=DateField]').setValue(Ext.Date.format(date, 'd.m.Y'));
         }
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
var inputDate = new Date('Mon Dec 08 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (RTZ 2 (winter))');
var output = Ext.Date.format(inputDate, 'd.m.Y'); // will output: 08.12.2014
```

Answer (score 0):

I make your solution using ES6. let is like var but only gets the context where the let declaration is declared. sometimes a function, other times a for, if... var declaration gets the context of their parent function. that means that doesn't respect fors or ifs or others just functions. The function that I provide is working.

```
let formatDate = (param) => {
  let day = param.getDate() < 10 ? '0' + param.getDate() : param.getDate();
  let month = (param.getMonth()+1);
  let year = param.getFullYear();

  return day +"."+ month +"."+ year;
}

let date = new Date("Mon Dec 08 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (RTZ 2 (winter))");

window.console.log(formatDate(date));
```